# What device is listed only as Android on list of devices that accessed my account?

Tags: security

I have an LG Optimus Zone 2. On the list of devices that have accessed my account one shows up as Android, but no other information is given. What type of device is this? Why aren't there any details shown for the device?

Comment: It is better if you mention that the list is available at Google. I didn't suspect it at first until I saw the answer by Lucky.

Answer (score 1):

Visit the [Devices and Activity](https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity) page to review the recent activity on a device. This page will show you the list of activities with all the devices you accessed your account with.

> You can see a list of devices that have accessed your account in the
>   last 28 days or are currently signed in to your account
>   Click on a device to see your last activity on it, including the last
>   date and time it connected to Google. For example, if you have apps
>   that automatically sync with Google, you’ll see the last time they
>   synced.

[image: DeviceActivity]

You can view the `Device`, `Location`, `Browser` and `Date & Time` information by clicking on that device. If you’re unsure about the activity, and think someone else may have access to your account, follow the steps to remove that device from your account.

[image: AndroidDeviceDetails]

<sub>----  Screenshot - Android Device Detailed Info  ---- [Source](http://techcloud.in/google-new-devices-and-activity-dashboard-helps-you-keep-track-of-your-devices/)</sub>

> **Remove device access**:   If you lose a device or notice any suspicious activity on it, you should remove the device’s access to
>   your account.
>
> 1. Go to your [Devices & activity](https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity) page.
> 2. Click on the device.
> 3. Click Remove access.
> 4. If you don’t see a button to remove access, follow the steps to [secure your account](https://security.google.com/settings/security/secureaccount)

Source: [See devices with access to your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3067630?p=devices&hl=en&rd=1)

Comment: Lucky, thanks, I didn't know about that page.